# Javascript and ASP create dynamic folders more elegantly

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have written the following script below - I am not quite happy with the script as I think it could be written in a more elegant and dynamic way...

I am using `ftp.exe` to ftp files from my application to another server.

If the folder structure does not exists on the web site. I need to create the folder stucture...

and doing it this way

```
mkdir folder1
mkdir folder1/folder2
mkdir folder1/folder2/folder3
```

with the script below I cater for a few `folder` lengths but not unlimited... so the solution will only work up to a certain amount of `sub folders`.

```
ftpmkdirlength = ftpmkdir.split('/').length-1
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<=ftpmkdirlength;i++)
{
ftpmkdir0 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir1 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir2 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir3 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir4 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir5 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir6 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir7 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir8 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir9 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir10 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.match(/\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\//) + "\n";
ftpmkdir1 = " mkdir " + ftpmkdir + ftpmkdir0 + ftpmkdir1 + ftpmkdir2 + ftpmkdir3 + ftpmkdir4 + ftpmkdir5 + ftpmkdir6 + ftpmkdir7 + ftpmkdir8 + ftpmkdir9+ ftpmkdir10;
ftpmkdir1 = ftpmkdir1.replace(/mkdir null/ig, '');
```

How can I make it more dynamic? so that the script see how many folders the input contains...

I can see the `folders full length` and get the folder like this `/folder1/folder2/folder3` but need to strip it to

```
folder1
folder1/folder2/
folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

and then create it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop, checking for indexes of `'/'` and using them to get parts of the full path.

```
var cmd = '';
var j, k;
var subpath;

if (ftpmkdir.length < 1 || ftpmkdir === '/') {
    throw 'no path';
}

j = ( ftpmkdir.indexOf('/', 0) === 0 ) ? 1 : 0; // provides non-slash starting point
k = ftpmkdir.indexOf('/', j);

while (k != -1) {
    subpath = ftpmkdir.substr(j, k - j); // get the path up to the current slash
    cmd += " mkdir " + subpath + "\n";
    k = ftpmkdir.indexOf('/', k + 1); ; // move the cursor
}

// check for additional path after last slash mark
if ((subpath + '/').length !== ftpmkdir.length - j) {
    cmd += " mkdir " + ftpmkdir.substr(j, ftpmkdir.length - j) + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow Lincolnk - Thank you very much for your troubles - the solution works perfectly! (as is and as provided by you)...

Answer (score 1):

A few different ideas pop in my head for helping here.

One idea is to consider that you can also just change directories after creating each one, so that you don't end up building such long paths. Here's an example of an FTP command sequence that would achieve the same thing:

```
mkdir folder1
cd folder1
(working directory is now /folder1/)
mkdir folder2
cd folder2
(working directory is now /folder1/folder2/)
mkdir folder3
cd folder3
(working directory is now /folder1/folder2/folder3/)
(etc...)
cd /   (to return "home" when finished)
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is something to think about... It makes sense to some degree.. Thanks for the input